# Trying to get the marker var out of the foreach loop for markerCluster to work, what is the easiest way of doing this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add MarkerClusters to my map, however my marker variable is within a function with a foreach loop used to retrieve Instagram API data, what is the best possible way to get MarkerClusters working?

I tried wrapping the initMap function around the setMarkers function, putting the markerCluster variable within the setMarkers function and within the foreach loop but it just keeps showing the markers (pictures in my case)

```
<script>
    let coords = document.getElementById("places").innerHTML;
    let parts = coords.split(",");

    let finalResult = []
    while (parts.length) {
        let newArr = parts.splice(0, 3);
        finalResult.push(newArr);
    }

    console.log(finalResult)


    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: {
                lat: 52.9,
                lng: 101.2
            }
        });
        setMarkers(map);
    }

    function setMarkers(map) {

        finalResult.forEach((place) => {

            var image = {
                url: place[0],
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 32)
            };

            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape
            });

        })
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    }

</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create the `MarkerClusterer` inside your `setMarkers` function, then add the markers to it individually as you create them with the `.addMarker` method.

```
function setMarkers(map) {
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  finalResult.forEach((place) => {
    var image = {
      url: place[0],
    };

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
    });
    markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8gjxa4kL/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let coords = document.getElementById("places").innerHTML;
let parts = coords.split(",");

let finalResult = []
while (parts.length) {
  let newArr = parts.splice(0, 3);
  finalResult.push(newArr);
}

console.log(finalResult)


function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -38,
      lng: 150
    }
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}

function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  finalResult.forEach((place) => {
    var image = {
      url: place[0],
    };

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);
    bounds.extend(myLatlng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
    });
    markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="places" style="display:none">https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-31.563910,147.154312, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-33.718234,150.363181, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-33.727111,150.371124, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-33.848588,151.209834,https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-33.851702,151.216968,
  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-34.671264,150.863657, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-35.304724,148.662905, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-36.817685,175.699196,https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-36.828611,175.790222,
  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.750000,145.116667, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.759859,145.128708, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.765015,145.133858,https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.770104,145.143299,
  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.773700,145.145187, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.774785,145.137978, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-37.819616,144.968119, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-38.330766,144.695692,
  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-39.927193,175.053218, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-41.330162,174.865694, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-42.734358,147.439506, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-42.734358,147.501315,
  https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-42.735258,147.438000, https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png,-43.999792,170.463352,
</div>
```